# Issue with laravel multi-level relationship eager loading trying to reaccess the parent model from the child model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I would like to ask on whats the best implementation on this one.

```
$users = User::with(['group', 'orders', 'comments'])->get()

$users->each(function($user) {
    $user->comments->each(function($comment) {
        // I know I can just add 'use' in the closure function to access the user again
        // but let's just say that the user variable is not accessible at this point of the code.
        // and the only way to access the user again is via $comment variable
        // when I access user here. it tries to fetch in the database
        $user = $comment->user;
    });
});
```

my 1st solution was to add this line of code.

```
$user->comments->setRelation('user', $user);
```

this would fix the issue as the user would not fetch in the database anymore.
but another problem arises. After setting the relation, the other eagerloaded user relationship will not be included in this level
such as the `$user->group`, and `$user->orders`.

here's my 2nd solution

```
$users = User::with([
'group',
'orders', 
'comments', 
// trying to eager load the comments user again
'comments.user', 
'comments.user.group', 
'comments.user.orders'])->get()
```

this would work but I don't think this is the best solution. especially when I have a lot of nested relationship that I eagerloaded.
I just limit it to 3 in the example to make it simplier.

Comment: In those cases better to use joins because eager loading under the hood makes an additional requests to the relational models

Comment: thank you for your response. but I don't think that's possible in my case. this is an existing system that I'm trying to optimize the report page for performance. there are a lot of things going on already on each eloquent models. and the fastest way us to eagerload everything without touching too much in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured how to fixed the issue.

`$user->comments->each->setRelation('user', $user);` will discard the eagerloaded models from $user.

but if you set the relation manually by `each`. all the eager loaded models will be included.

```
$user->comments->each(function($comment) use ($user) {
     $comment->setRelation('user', $user);
});
```